# Why do I fail to save data in my application?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am a student and started working on android studio recently. I don't know about it much. I am working on an application where I save the item name and its amount in the database and display toast message if data we entered is saved or not. problem is whenever I click on the save button my application crashes.

**following is my DatabaseHelper class:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Items.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "item_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "ITEM";
    public static final String COL_3 = "AMOUNT";


    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + "ITEM TEXT, AMOUNT TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean addData(String item, String amount){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,item);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,item);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }


    }


}
```

**following is my MainActivity class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editItem, editAmount;
    Button buttonSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        editItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.item_field);
        editAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount_field);
        buttonSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_save);

        AddData();

    }

    public void AddData(){
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String item = editItem.getText().toString();
                String amount = editAmount.getText().toString();

                boolean insertData = myDb.addData(item, amount);

                if(insertData == true){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Amount is saved with Item detail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occurred : Detailed are not saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

I will appreciate your help.
Thank you

Comment: If your app is failing then edit your  post the error that you are receiving so we can determine why from the stack. You should use debugging and stack traces when encountering errors to help troubleshoot them.

Comment: you will find your error in the logcat https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat Please edit your post to include the specific error here.

Comment: Thank you my issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be crashing because it's not creating the table:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + "ITEM TEXT, AMOUNT TEXT)";
```

A space is missing between table and its name:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ITEM TEXT, AMOUNT TEXT)";
```

You should also close the database after you get the data in db.insert but this only creates a warning:

```
long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, contentValues);
db.close();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help